# How to change number base and direction with emmet

Tags: visual-studio-code, emmet

In regards to an [official document](https://docs.emmet.io/abbreviations/syntax/) on emmet usage for changing number direction, the following *should* work in numbering values in reverse order:

`ul>li.item$@-*5`

But...that does not work in Visual Studio Code version 1.43.2

What is the proper emmet syntax for listing out the following numbers like so...

```
<ul>
    <li class="item5"></li>
    <li class="item4"></li>
    <li class="item3"></li>
    <li class="item2"></li>
    <li class="item1"></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the ability to count down will be added to v1.53, see pre-release notes https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_53.md#emmet-performance-and-feature-improvements

> Emmet now works much faster in large HTML and CSS files. Also, the
> extension now uses the latest Emmet dependency, meaning that features
> such as countdowns are now supported.

It looks like you had the proper syntax.

------  previously ::

It doesn't work in vscode.  See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/87657 and https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/69168 and https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/35296.

It is on the Backlog but deosn't appear to being actively addressed.  Vote up the issues.